# prevent form autofill in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

i have a text field in a form

```
<form action="">
<input type="text" id="input_id"></input>
<button type="button" id="button_id"></input>
.
.
.
</form>
```

each time i entered some values in the input field, there seems to be a recored where it is stored, and then when i entered some other values, those already entered come up as suggestion type, but i don't want that to happen. How can i disable this for that particular field. forgive me if i sound ignorant but i'm blind here... any suggestion and help will be highly appreciated. i don't have a clue how to start.

Comment: Your question made no mention of cookies, I edited the title.

Comment: Input elements don't have a closing tag. Button elements have a closing tag of `</button>`. ;-|

Comment: @Barmar... as you wish!!!! that's because i don't actually understand my problem.

Comment: @RobG input element with closing tag doesn't give errors either... so i never knew it....i'll try to be more carefull next time around then...

Comment: @L4reds—browsers are very tolerant of erroneous HTML—they will do their best to correct it and rarely (if ever) throw errors, though the consequences of error correction may be different in different browsers and may produce unexpected results. A redundant closing tag will just be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maybe add `autocomplete="off"` attribute to the textbox.

```
<input type="text" id="input_id" autocomplete="off" />
```

And if this doesn't work, you could generate some random `data-*` attributes using JavaScript in `ready` event (Assuming your form isnt dynamic), like this :

```
$(function () {
  $("#input_id").attr("data-random", Math.random());
});
```

This will give a simulation to the browser that this is different element and hence won't bring the autocomplete data to the text box.

For dynamic `input`, here's the jQuery way :

```
$("form").append($("<input />", {
    "type": "text",
    "class": "V_NAME",
    "name": "V_NAME",
    "id": "NAME" + array[l],
    "autocomplete": "off",
    "data-random": Math.random()
}));
```

Comment: my input field is dynamically generated and when i add .append($("<input />", {
            type: "text",
            class: "V_NAME", 
            name: "V_NAME",
            id: "NAME" + array[l],
   autocomplete: "off"
        })) the autocomplete it gives this error Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on autocomplete prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'off'

Comment: add `""` around autocomplete.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#NAME"+array[l]).attr("autocomplete", "off");
  }); seem to work just fine..... your comment "(Assuming your form isnt dynamic)" helps me alot.

Comment: @L4reds glad to help :) just in case the browser ur site is opened in doesnt support that attribute, add the random attribute to it.. see my answer edit

Answer (score 3):

This depend on  browser 
Add this tag to textbox

This Property Supported by the Browser which showing values you've typed in that field before.

You can turn off this property by :

```
    <form id="Form1" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="input_id"></input>
...
</form>
```

Comment: this answer is equally helpful too

Answer (score 2):

set autocomplete to "off" to disable the suggestions

Comment: +1 'cos I like answers that don't involve incorrect HTML. :-)